# Managing software compatibility between multiple development environments?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, development-environment

I'm setting up new computer (Windows 8 Pro x64) with development tools needed for my new job.  Whereas in past positions I was working in mainly one environment, I now am developing across those environments.  After spending the last 12 hours digging through my registry to find out how an opensource BI/Analytics tool screwed up my local install of SAP among other things.

Currently I'm working on projects in the following environments:

- SAP
- JRuby, Rails
- Python
- R
- CSS, Bootstrap
- VB.NET

For each of these projects I've got several tools and git repos to keep track of.  I'm new to the development world coming from the Analytics/Business Process Management one.  Suggestions for any utilities, tools, best practices, etc... for managing these environments on my workstation would be welcomed.  I use GitHub and other PM tools for the projects themselves but its the environments I need to keep track of now.

Thanks,

-J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use VMWare Workstation 9.0.

It's perfect, and I use it for several environment too..

Hope this helps.